# Como fazer efeito de baixo relevo em textos?

Tags: css

Gostaria de fazer um efeito de baixo relevo em um texto. Usando a propriedade `text-shadow` é possível fazer isso, como mostro abaixo:

```css
.box{
   font-family: Arial;
   background: #bababa;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
   font-size: 4em;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   Texto
</div>
```

O problema é que no meu projeto, a div onde está o texto possui um background mais claro do que no exemplo acima (`background: #f5f5f5;`), e com isso, o efeito do `text-shadow` fica imperceptível devido ao baixo contraste entre o `background` e a cor do `text-shadow`, veja:

```css
.box{
   font-family: Arial;
   background: #f5f5f5;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
   font-size: 4em;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   Texto
</div>
```

Seria algo semelhante ao valor `inset` da propriedade `box-shadow`, mas o `box-shadow` só se aplica a tags de conteúdo (`div`, `span` etc.) e não a textos.

É possível fazer esse efeito de baixo relevo em textos com CSS? Como?

Comment: Sam seria interessante vc incluir na sua pergunta uma imagem com um exemplo o mais próximo possível do que vc quer, pois existem varias técnicas e vários estilos de baixo e alto relevo

Comment: Oi Hugo! O snippet não basta?

Comment: Acho que não Sam ate Pq na sua própria resposta vc fala que encontrou um Codepen com efeito "semelhante" ao que vc quer, então nem seu snippet, nem o codepen parecem ser o que vc quer... Logo, seria legal vc incluir uma imagem para a gente não perder tempo te dando uma resposta que tbm não eh o que vc tem em mente, já que o efeito pode ser feito com formas e técnicas diferentes com o falei...

Comment: @hugocsl Então, seria algo semelhante ao primeiro snippet, e o Codepen que achei ficou a contento com o sombreado interno, porque, pelo menos à princípio, a questão do contraste da sombra branca com o background, que daria o efeito mostrado no snippet, é o que prejudica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pesquisando no Google encontrei um Codepen que faz um efeito semelhante que ficou a contento:

```css
.box{
   font-family: Arial;
   background: #f5f5f5;
   font-size: 4em;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 20px;   
}

.box span{
   color: transparent;
   background-color: #000; /* cor do texto */
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -moz-background-clip: text;
   background-clip: text; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <span>Texto</span>
</div>
```

Além do `text-shadow`, é utilizada a propriedade `background-clip: text` em conjunto com `color: transparent` e `background-color` gerando um sombreamento interno no texto, criando um efeito ótico de que a parte interna do texto é mais baixa do que por fora.

No Chrome e Opera a propriedade `background-clip` necessita do prefixo `-webkit-`.